# DataContractJsonExample error of deserializing

Tags: c#

When I'm running script it throw error with text:
There was an error deserializing the object of type Tutorial10.DataContractJsonExample.Customer. Encountered unexpected character 'D'."

What's wrong?

```
    internal class DataContractJsonSerialization
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer()
            {
                Name = "Sas",
                Age = 21,
                Email = "email@email.com",
                Weight = 75.4,
                IsAlive = true,
                Orders = new Order[] {
                    new Order() {
                        Price = 400,
                        Name = "Cake"
                    },
                    new Order() {
                        Price = 20.5,
                        Name = "Apple"
                    }
                }

            };
            WriteObject("DataContractJsonSerialization.json", customer);
            ReadObject("DataContractJsonSerialization.json");
        }
        public static void WriteObject(string fileName, Customer customer)
        {

            FileStream writer = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser =
                new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Customer));
            ser.WriteObject(writer, customer);
            writer.Close();

        }

        public static void ReadObject(string fileName)
        {
            var deserializedUser = new Customer();
            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName));
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(deserializedUser.GetType());
            deserializedUser = ser.ReadObject(ms) as Customer;
            ms.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Can you share the sample json?

Comment: You're trying to deserialize the file name, not the json contained in that file

Comment: @Chetan You can see it in code, but if it's needed:
{"Age":30,"Email":"email@email.com","IsAlive":true,"Name":"Jan","Orders":[{"Name":"Cake","Price":400},{"Name":"Apple","Price":20.5}],"Weight":75.4}

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson cannot understand what you mean

Comment: `WriteObject` opens a FileStream using the file name, and writes the object to that stream. `ReadObject` opens a MemoryStream, and fills the contents of it with the file name. It _should_ open a FileStream and read from it instead